# How to pass all props and still enable suggestion or autocomplete or intelliSense VScode in React/ React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, react-props

Autocomplete makes coding easier. When I use `TouchableOpacity`, I get suggestions of its props like `onPress`, `accessible`, etc. But when I use it like this,

```
export default function Button(props) {
return <TouchableOpacity {...props}>{props.children}</TouchableOpacity>
}
```

the suggestions go away. Is there a way to enable the suggestions when passing all props?

Comment: i got it. I can’t autocomplete with js. I have to use typescript.